# Do not understand the error in Neo4j creation of nodes.

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a node

create (n:node0{78 : 78});

This results in an error of

Invalid input ':': expected whitespace, comment or '}' (line 1, column 20 (offset: 19))
"create (n:node0{78 : 78})"
                    ^

The book I am following "Learning Neo4j" by Bruggen, Packt Publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that "78" cannot be a key name (most likely because it starts with a digit) and the correct code should be like

```
create (n:node0{param78: 78})
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, I figured that out. I am using backticks to solve the problem.